# Canada vector data

Tags: polygon, data, canada

I am looking for vector data -> Landuse [residential, commercial, industrial, cropland, water etc.]

Scale : best possible but would like 1:50 000 or better 
Location : NL, BC, QC

I checked various source, but I find Canvec, OSM, EOSD Landcover, Geofabrik  are very  coarse  or missing (St John's is almost empty as far as data)

Any source I should check (paid or free) so I can produce Nice thematic maps

Comment: You will need to go to Municipality level (not Provincial/Federal Level) for this type of data, some Opendata portals (Vancouver http://data.vancouver.ca/datacatalogue/index.htm or St Johns http://www.saintjohn.ca/en/home/living/maps/default.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Natural Resources Canada Geogratis (CanVec) 1:50,000 is the best and most up to date Canada-wide data available, at [Open Data Canada](https://open.canada.ca/en/external-entity/solr_inventory-10140e7cdfd24567021e863d75ed5ea4).
This is the same data used in the official CanTopo CanMatrix 1:50000 paper maps and the same data that's used for the ArcGIS Online World Topographic basemap altough GeoBase, Agriculture and Agri-Food Canada are also listed.

Each province also has their own geospatial data warehouses but not all are free. In Ontario Land Information Ontario (LIO) data has free 1:10,000 and 1:20,000 data both vector and raster, but in BC this is a paid service.

You could also try [GeoBase data](https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset?q=geobase).